# Why the text doesnt appear aligned?

Tags: css

I have this [css](https://jsfiddle.net/pbhtwq53/) and its working fine the text appears at right and is aligned.

However the same code of that fiddle in a pdf, the text is apeparing like this (like the example at right, at left is how it should display):

[image: desired output left, rendered output right]

Do you know what can be the issue?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span">1.</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint vel aut quidem consequatur quaerat optio ab! Iste fugit nostrum odio dolorum sequi, odit ratione omnis, atque sunt perferendis commodi, iure.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely the PDF converter you are using can't handle flex properly

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to achive the layout without the flex property?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using `text-align`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.span {

  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="span">1.</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint vel aut quidem consequatur quaerat optio ab! Iste fugit nostrum odio dolorum sequi, odit ratione omnis, atque sunt perferendis commodi, iure.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue with that approach.

Comment: Note that text-justify: inter-word; only supported by some version of FF, EDGE, and IE. Not Chrome. Check this: https://caniuse.com/css-text-justify

Answer (score -2):

@mehran `text-justify:inter-word;` is not a valid CSS property

Comment: Not actually correct. It is valid for IE 10-11 and EDGE 12-18, also valid for some version of FF - https://caniuse.com/css-text-justify